# I want to design a shipping option, for standard and express in django

Tags: html, django

```
forms.py
    SHIPPING_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Standard'),
        ('E', 'Express'),
    )
    
    class Shipping(forms.Form):
        shipping_option = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=SHIPPING_CHOICES)
views.py
    class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
                form = Shipping()
                context = {
                        'form' : form,
                        'object' : order,
                        'couponform': CouponForm(),
                        'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': True,
    
                    }
                return render(self.request, 'cart.html', context)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
                return redirect('estores:home')
                                    
        
        def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
            form = Shipping(self.request.POST)
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False) 
            if form.is_valid:
                shipping_option = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_option')
                if shipping_option == 'S':
                    order.options ='Standard'
                    order.save()
    
                elif shipping_option == 'E':
                    order.options = 'Express'
                    order.save()
html
    <form  method="POST">
        {% for value, name in form.fields.shipping_option.choices %}
            <tr class="summary-shipping-row">
                <td>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="{{ name }}" type="radio" name="shipping_option" value="{{ value }}" class="custom-control-input" required>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

I want to retrieve the value of the form option and save it to my order shipping option.
anytime i am on the cart page, there should be two options for shipping. either standard or express and i want to be able to add the shipping prices to the order price.